# what are the two little bars on the left side of T400 Laptop

Tags: laptop

On the left side of my Lenovo T400, before the floppy disk drive, there are two plastic little bars.  When pushing either of them, it can pop out; if push it again, it can go back inside.

I was wondering what these bars are used for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know the laptop, but is sounds like the blanks for a [PC-Card](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC_Card) (PCMCIA) slot. These cards were typically used for modems or other I/O expansion cards.

Comment: I am not sure if the bars are what you are guessing. They are plastic and look like two half-length matchsticks. They are close to each other, with one on top of the other.

Comment: thats the release buttons for the pcmcia card(s). The blanks typically arn't full depth so sometimes they dont engage the release, but when you have an actual pcmcia card in the slot it'll pop out when you push the button back in. I believe on thinkpads these buttons are typically blue.

Comment: photo would be good then :) it's either 2x PC-Card or a couple of SD Card slots, although the former seems a more likely